# Unit of work Pattern sequence

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, unit-of-work

I was trying to use unit of work pattern to use transaction, so that all the database changes are committed at once.

As i have seen in tutorials, on calling Commit method, i loop through the list for added entity, then changed and then deleted and call their repository method.

But if in case, i have a requirement, that i first delete an item and then add a new one (if value is unique, i need to remove first, then add). I know i can update it, but just say if i want it this way, then no matter which method i call first, when i will commit, it will initially add and then remove, so how to make a proper squence?

Answer (score 1):

Aggregates involved in Units of Work have unique identities in order to track changes to the aggregate over the aggregate's lifetime. Unless two aggregates have the same identity they are not the same aggregate even if their attributes are identical.

The order established in the Unit of Work pattern prohibits manipulation of non-existent aggregates. If the order were to be changed, the behaviour would break, and for that reason can't be altered.

If your requirement is to delete an aggregate and recreate it with the same identity, this will break the uniqueness of the aggregate.

It is worth spending some time looking into the business requirement. Could the actual requirement be to reset the state of the aggregate? This would be identical to creating a new aggregate with the same identity but with the added benefit of maintaining the aggregate's entire history if needed.

Alternatively you can delete the old aggregate and create a new one but it will not be the same aggregate for the reasons given above. Dependent aggregates referencing the old aggregate could then be reassigned to reference the new aggregate in its place.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing about UnitOfWork is that you don't need to bother with those low level details. If you think the outcome will be different, then you should force it your way but not expect a UnitOfWork to do it in *ANY* predictable way. When the database technology is change to something unprecedented there is no guarantee on how the actual result will be obtained. What you get is *only* a guarantee that the result will be the same no matter what.

So if you really cannot abstract that mechanic view because of a legacy constraint of some sort you maybe are better off not using this high level tool to do the job. Revert to actual transactions and explicit sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how NHibernate does it. As good a model as you're going to get.

> The SQL statements are issued in the following order
>
> all entity insertions, in the same order the corresponding objects
>   were saved using ISession.Save()
>
> all entity updates
>
> all collection deletions
>
> all collection element deletions, updates and insertions
>
> all collection insertions
>
> all entity deletions, in the same order the corresponding objects were
>   deleted using ISession.Delete()